# text-decoration for a Link in Material-UI is not working. Any solution?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

I am working on React/Next js project and using MUI for designing.

```
<Link href="/products">
            <ListItem disablePadding>
              <ListItemButton>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <HomeIcon />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary="Home"/>
              </ListItemButton>
            </ListItem>
          </Link>
```

I tried inline css "<ListItemText primary="Home"/ sx={{textDecoration:'none'}}>" but its not working.

Comment: Consider editing your question to describe how "it is not working". It is not clear what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, try applying the `textDecorationStyle` property to your `Link` element.

Answer (score 0):

For ReactJs you can add css as:

```
<Link component={Link} to="/products" sx={{textDecoration: "none",
textTransform: "none", color:"black"}}>
            <ListItem disablePadding>
              <ListItemButton>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <HomeIcon />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary="Home"/>
              </ListItemButton>
            </ListItem>
          </Link>
```